# Promise inside Observable in Angular 7+

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-storage

I have a problem that I can't solve.

In the `ngOnInit` event I observe the url parameter. This parameter corresponds to a folder in *firebase-storage*. That way when loading I get a list of folders and/or files inside that folder that is being informed and storing it inside `listReferences` variable which is of type Reference[].

Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.getFiles(params.ref).subscribe(
        (listReferences) => {
          this.listReferences = listReferences;
        }
      );
    }
  );
}

getFiles(folder: string) {
  return this.storage.ref('/' + folder).listAll()
  .pipe(
    map((data) => {
      return data.items;
    })
  );
}
```

It turns out that for each item in the `listReferences` array I need to access the `getDownloadUrl()` or `getMetadata()` method which are promising and I am unable to retrieve the values for each item in the array. How should I proceed in this case? How best to do this?

Basically I am following the information contained in the reference guide.
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference](http://Basically%20I%20am%20following%20the%20information%20contained%20in%20the%20reference%20guide.%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference)

Comment: Maybe you can use the callback function for this problem.

Comment: how exactly would that be done? I tried to make a map in the array as in the [code snippet below](https://codepen.io/miguelsneto/pen/wvMqYzz.js) ... but it didn't work ...

Comment: Where is getMetadata located in your code? is it listReference consists of entities having getMetadata method as their propety?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `ForkJoin` as follows:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(x => this.getFiles(x.ref)),
      mergeMap((listReferences: { getDownloadUrl: () => Promise<string> }[]) => {
        return forkJoin(listReferences.map(x => x.getDownloadUrl()))
      })
    )
    .subscribe(x =>  this.urls = x)
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the line `mergeMap((listReferences: { getDownloadUrl: () => Promise<string> }[]) => {`

Comment: would i need 2 mergeMap? One to promise getMetadata () and another to promise getDownloadUrl () ???

Comment: **at the end of the process i need to have an array where each item has its original value + promisse value `getMetadata()` + promisse value `getDownloadUrl()`**

Comment: I see, why don't you post your interface, so I can understand  the way you want it to be at the final process?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference

Comment: Where do you want to store the result of `getDownloadUrl() ` and the other methods you are using?

Comment: in the array itself... I need to complement the array with the result of getDownloadUrl and getMetadata

Comment: where is the array located? please post an interface

Comment: I need to fill a ul list in the view and so I would like to have an array with all the information complete You can see her: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nyic4c